# Defining constants in Swift

Tags: swift, memory, static, constants

I noticed that very popular technique for defining constants in Swift looks like this:

```
struct Constants {
        static let fileDownloadTimeOut: TimeInterval = 45 * 60
        static let timeout: TimeInterval = 60
        static let perPageCount = 10
        static let usersPerPageCount = 15
}
```

From one point of view - it looks very neat and nice when it comes to syntax. BUT, the problem I'm finding is an overwhelming usage of static variables.

As far as I know, `static` variables behave the same way in `Swift` as those do in `C++`. Those variables are inited during compile time and remain in the memory till the app is dead.

Problems I'm finding with this approach are next:

1) Polluted `RAM`. I understand that those times when developers save every byte of the memory has passed, but still it doesn't mean that we should not maintain our storage resources properly.

2) I have a big background of `C++` and I'm finding such technique as a "bad taste". I was always discouraged to use `static` variables for "syntax sugar", and that's why I'm used to create a `static` variable only when I absolutely need it.

The thing is - I searched web for a quite long time to find some other suggestions to define constants nicely in `Swift`, but I found absolutely nothing except this approach with a struct with a bunch of static variables.

I understand approach with `static let` constants when it comes to creating `Singleton` or the object which lives forever till the app dies. But what I noticed that this exact approach is also recommended for usage in view controllers or other temporary objects and logically this is wrong.

Am I overreacting on this trend and that's one of things that changed and accepted by other developers community? I hope to get some opinions on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806982/difference-between-static-function-and-singleton-class-in-swift/37812213#37812213

Comment: Hello @RaziTiwana! Although this is a very valid opinion I'm not sure it fits my question. Are you implying that addressing static constant is a lot faster than addressing a usual variable?