# Swift: too many static functions?

Tags: swift, macos

I have a class that represents Calendar items (model) retrieved from the event store.  I haven't implemented any delegation yet for the AppDelegate or ViewControllers.

All my methods in this class are static functions - the main reason is so that I can "see" them from the AppDelegate or the VC.  I have a suspicion that:

1) I need to make this a singleton - whose only function is to retrieve calendar items from the eventStore and post to the UI

2) learn how to code better - perhaps creating an instance of the class in the AppDelegate and the VC

This is still very fuzzy to me - not sure if posting code would help, but the class has a bunch of **"static func .... doSomething() { ...}"** and is called by the AppDelegate and VC as **"ClassName.doSomething()..."**

I'm prepared to refactor the Class code, thinking that a singleton would work - or perhaps things are just fine as they are...

EDITED: Adding code:

```
import Foundation
import EventKit


class Calendars: NSObject {

    enum calendarAuthState {
        case restricted
        case authorized
        case denied
        case notDetermined
    }

    struct Calendar {
        var id: String
        var color: NSColor
        var title: String
        var isUserActive: Bool
        var events: [EventItem]


    }
    struct EventItem {
        var originalStartDate: Date
        var date: String
        var title: String
        var isAllDayEvent: Bool
    }

    static var calendarState: calendarAuthState = .notDetermined
    static var eventStore = EKEventStore()
    static var currentCalendars = [Calendar]()



    //MARK: Check Calendar Authorization Status
    static func calendarAuthorizationStatus() {
        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
        switch (status) {
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
            // This happens on first-run
            calendarState = .notDetermined
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized:
            calendarState = .authorized
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.restricted:
            self.requestAccessToCalendar()
            calendarState = .restricted
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.denied:
            self.requestAccessToCalendar() 
            calendarState = .denied
        }
    }

    static func requestAccessToCalendar() {
        self.eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event, completion: {
            (accessGranted: Bool, error: Error?) in
            if accessGranted == true {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.calendarState = .authorized
                })
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.calendarState = .denied
                })
            }
        })
    }

        //MARK: Do the two below
        static func createMenuFromCalendars() {
            guard calendarState == .authorized else {
                return
            }
            let calendars = self.returnCalendars()
            guard calendars.count >= 0 else {
                return
            }
            self.addCalendarsToMenuItems(from: calendars)

        }

    //MARK: First, return the calendar titles from the Store
    static func returnCalendars() -> [Calendar] {
        guard self.calendarState == .authorized else {
            return[]
        }
        let calendars = self.eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
        for calendar in calendars {
            self.currentCalendars.append(Calendar(id: calendar.calendarIdentifier, color: calendar.color, title: calendar.title, isUserActive: false, events: []))
        }
        return self.currentCalendars
    }

    //MARK: Next, send those to the Menu for MenuItem creation
    static func addCalendarsToMenuItems(from calendars:[Calendar]) {
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let appMainMenu = NSApp.mainMenu

        if let calendarMenu = appMainMenu?.item(withTitle: "Calendars") {
            let calendarSubMenu = calendarMenu.submenu

            for calendar in calendars {
                let menuItem = calendarSubMenu?.addItem(withTitle: calendar.title, action: #selector(appDelegate.actionFromSelectedCalendar) , keyEquivalent: "")
                menuItem?.isEnabled = true
                menuItem?.state = .off
                menuItem?.target = appDelegate.self
                menuItem?.toolTip = calendar.id

            }

        }
    }

     class func retrieveCalendarEvents() {
        guard self.calendarState == .authorized || !(self.currentCalendars.isEmpty) else {
            return
        }
        let startDate = Date()
        let endDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 4*24*3600)
        var activeCalendars = findUserActiveCalendars(in: currentCalendars)
        //need to flush the events at this stage or they'll pile
        guard !((activeCalendars?.isEmpty)!) else {
            return
        }
        var eventCalendar = [EKCalendar]()
        for dayBookCalendar in activeCalendars! {
            // much of the risk here is unwrapping optionals unsafely!!!!! - refactor this and other please
            eventCalendar.append(self.eventStore.calendar(withIdentifier: dayBookCalendar.id)!)
            let eventPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, calendars: eventCalendar)
            let returnedEvents = eventStore.events(matching: eventPredicate)
            let calendarIndex = findCalendarIndex(by: dayBookCalendar.id, in: currentCalendars)
            for event in returnedEvents {
                let eventItems = eventItem(from: event)
                currentCalendars[calendarIndex!].events.append(eventItems)
            }
        }

    }

    //MARK: Helper methods and stuff
    static func changeUserCalendarState(with id:String, state:Bool) {
        guard !(currentCalendars.isEmpty) else {
            return
        }
        let calendarIndex = findCalendarIndex(by: id, in:self.currentCalendars)
        if let calendarIndex = calendarIndex {
            currentCalendars[calendarIndex].isUserActive = !state
            retrieveCalendarEvents()
        }
    }

    static func findCalendarIndex(by id:String, in calendarArray: [Calendar]) -> Int? {
        return calendarArray.index(where: {$0.id == id})
    }

    static func findUserActiveCalendars(in calendarArray: [Calendar]) -> [Calendar]? {
        return calendarArray.filter({$0.isUserActive == true})
    }

//    static func flushEventsFromCalendar(in calendarArray: inout [Calendar]) {
//        calendarArray.map({$0.events.removeAll()})
//    }
    static func eventItem(from events:EKEvent) -> EventItem {
        return EventItem(originalStartDate: events.startDate, date:eventTime(from: events.startDate), title: events.title!, isAllDayEvent: events.isAllDay)
    }

    static func parseCalendarEvents(from events:[EKEvent]) -> [EventItem] {  //can this be variadic?
        var calendarEvents = [EventItem]()
        for event in events {
            calendarEvents.append(eventItem(from: event))

        }
        return calendarEvents

    }

    static func eventTime(from date:Date) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        let stringTime = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return stringTime
    }


}
```

''

Comment: Maybe head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I'm guessing you'll get downvoted here for "too broad" or "opinion-based"

Comment: @Gereon: Code Review requires working code from a concrete project. In its present form the question would be off-topic (lacking context) on CR.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806982/difference-between-static-function-and-singleton-class-in-swift.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making an elementary mistake about object-oriented programming. In your Calendars class you seem to have encapsulated all the code for accessing the user's calendar. Then you seem to have reasoned: "Well, this code needs to be callable from anywhere. Therefore all my class's members need to be global (static / class)."

That's a mistake. There is nothing wrong with doing such encapsulation; indeed it's a good thing. But then the way to *use* your encapsulation is with a helper *instance*. For example, let's say you're in a view controller (which is most likely after all). Then it can have a property:

```
let calendarHelper = Calendars()
```

Now all (or nearly all) your members can (and should) become *instance* members. Remember, instances of the same type each get to maintain state separately from one another; that is part of their encapsulation. You're going to want that ability.

If your underlying reason for thinking you need static/class members is that you only want *one* EKEventStore instance for the life of the app, then push the globalness / staticness down to that *one* object (e.g. by a "shared" EKEventStore and methods for accessing it) and let everything *else* be a normal instance member.

Comment: For a typical example of this pattern, see my https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift. Here we have a class ManagerHolder which does for CLLocationManager what your class does for EKEventStore. Look at how the view controller incorporates an _instance_ of this class.

Comment: matt - thank you for this - this is very insightful - I can also see how this topic can get into the gray opinion-based realm - but your approach seems sensible here - I think a lot of rookie coders (myself) are faced with the 'daunting' tasks of learning patterns such as delegation, dependency injection etc - that is why I asked my question: I want to tackle these issue as it's the only way to really learn.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've said, suspicion 1) is correct - you need to use a [singleton](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift):

```
class CalendarService {

    private var eventStore = EKEventStore()

    //Static shared instance, this is your singleton 
    static var sharedInstance =  CalendarService()

    //Your public methods for adding events can go here
    public func doSomething() {
        //...
    }

    //As can your private methods for producing, deleting and editing calendar events + checking permissions

}
```

Usage:

```
CalendarService.sharedInstance.doSomething()
```

I can't really say much more without specific examples of your existing code.

Comment: thanks for the input - added code to the original post

Comment: Okay, so you need a `static var sharedInstance =  Calendars()` (as above) to ensure that you have a singleton. Then you can go through and remove `static` / `class` prefixes, exposing only what you need to as `public` via `Calendars.sharedInstance.yourPublicMethod()`, for example. I would recommend renaming `Calendars` as `CalendarService` to make it obvious that this is the singleton for dealing with creating/deleting/editing calendar events.

Comment: thanks for this - I also read the links you provided and they were great to read too -